# How to build crossplatform images with GitLab Runner and docker executuor

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cross-platform, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to build an aarch64 image using [GitLab's Docker-in-Docker configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker) for a Runner with the docker executor. Ideally the build should be done using docker-compose and specifying the build platform in the Dockerfiles.

The `config.toml`'s runners section looks like this:

```ini
[[runners]]
  name = "myrunner"
  url = "xxx"
  token = "xxx"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/certs/client", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

The `.gitlab-ci.yml`like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - build

variables:
  DOCKER_BUILDKIT: "1"
  COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD: "1"
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

services:
  - docker:20.10.16-dind

docker_build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:20.10.16
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker-compose --version
    - docker buildx version
  script:
    - ...
    - docker-compose build
```

The `before_script` output:

```bash
$ docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.8.2)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.5.1)
Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.16
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 212e8b6fa2f44b9c21b2798135fc6fb7c53efc16
 runc version: v1.1.1-0-g52de29d7
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.0-73-generic
 Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.15 (containerized)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 7.775GiB
 Name: b90e885189b8
WARNING: No swap limit support
 ID: ULYB:ANXP:MZRN:BTTF:BIER:OCV3:SVF5:HUAB:BW2V:SDSJ:ZOMU:ZZWZ
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
$ docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.5.1
$ docker buildx version
github.com/docker/buildx v0.8.2 6224def4dd2c3d347eee19db595348c50d7cb491
```

For good measure, I also enabled BuildKit in the host's daemon.json:

```json
{ "features": { "buildkit": true } }
```

However, if I try to build from a Dockerfile that specifies aarch64 as the build platform the build will fail, for example at the first `npm install`. (amd64 images from the same Dockerfile and Runner are building without issues).
Example Dockerfile:

```
ARG BUILD_PLATFORM

FROM --platform=$BUILD_PLATFORM node:lts-alpine

RUN npm install -g http-server

WORKDIR /svelte-frontend

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD http-server public --port 3000 --proxy http://localhost:3000?
```

I have also tried using [Docker socket binding](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding) with the same result.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried using `buildx bake` with the following commands:

```yaml
...
script:
    # Create new docker-compose file with substituted variables
    # for use with buildx bake
    - docker-compose config > docker-compose.buildx.yml
    # Build images using buildx bake
    - docker buildx bake -f docker-compose.buildx.yml
```

But the build still fails, even though buildx is now clearly being used.

**UPDATE 2:**
Re-initializing the binfmt handlers as desribed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63555735/14906871) did the trick for me. This means adding the following to the `before_script`:

```yaml
...
  before_script:
    - docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes 
    - ...
```